# I'm trying to echo javascript with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm a beginner, so i hope you can understand me.

I want it to echo a javascript code when the cookie named usr is not false.
The first echo works perfectly but the jquery won't work at all.

```
<?php 
require('checker.php');
$result = checker::isExpired($_COOKIE["hash"]);
$_COOKIE["usr"] = $result;
if ($result != false) {
    echo '<span style"color:red;">szeretlek java</span>';
    echo '<script src="js/jquery.js">';
    echo 'var result = $.cookie("usr");';
    echo 'var added = "Hello, " + result;';
    echo '$(function {
    $("#brand_div").html("alma");
    });';
    echo '</script>';
}
else {
echo "";
}
?>
```

Comment: Any error shown in `console` ?

Comment: You need to put your code in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: He has a `script` tag.

Comment: Do you need () after function: echo '$(function() {

Comment: I forgot to copy in the ending php tag but it is there

Comment: @Marcel1997 A `<script>` can either have a src or contain code, not both.

Comment: @gcampbell, thanks alot^^ i forgot. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to echo 2 scripts in one `<script></script>` tag set.

So amend your code like this adding the script tag for your hand coded script after you include jQuery

```
<?php 
require('checker.php');
$result = checker::isExpired($_COOKIE["hash"]);
$_COOKIE["usr"] = $result;
if ($result != false) {
    echo '<span style"color:red;">szeretlek java</span>';
    echo '<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'var result = $.cookie("usr");';
        echo 'var added = "Hello, " + result;';
        echo '$(function() {
                $("#brand_div").html("alma");
            });';
    echo '</script>';
}
else {
    echo "";
}
```

Comment: Still not working. it prints "szeretlek java" but the jquery script isn't working at all.

Comment: See `function()` with a `()`

Comment: You do know about the javascript debugger available in all browsers I can think of dont you. Normally activated by a F12. Look at the console tab, it should show you javascript errors

Comment: this is the error: TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
<névtelen>

Answer (score 3):

Close the script tag for first echo and use separate script tag for  your custom function.also add parenthesis for function().

```
<?php 
require('checker.php');
$result = checker::isExpired($_COOKIE["hash"]);
$_COOKIE["usr"] = $result;
if ($result != false) {
    echo '<span style"color:red;">szeretlek java</span>';
    echo '<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'var result = $.cookie("usr");';
    echo 'var added = "Hello, " + result;';
    echo '$(function() {
    $("#brand_div").html("alma");
   });';
    echo '</script>';
}
else {
echo "";
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Ganesh Jagtap, edited `echo '<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>';`
and added `echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; ` So first look right and then leave such bad comments. THX!

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are few error in your code.
in Js you must give "()" for functions.
In the below code instead for reading from COOKIE i give variable please change that and also include   require('checker.php');
The below code is a working example for your query , you need to add your pages and variables.

```
<?php 
$result = "Sdfsf";
if ($result != false) {
    echo '<span style"color:red;">szeretlek java</span>';
    echo '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo "var result = '$result';";
    echo 'var added = "Hello, " + result;';
    echo '$(function() {
    $("#brand_div").html("alma");
   });';
    echo '</script>';
}
else {
echo "";
}
?>
 <div id="brand_div" class="brand_div">  </div>
```